Why are X-ray diffraction (XRD) peaks the same for some different lattice planes?
I have some XRD measurements of a sample and wanted to compare them with the literature to find out the quality of my sample. To my understanding, the XRD peak for my sample corresponds to the (001) plane, but when I looked up research papers on the same material, I noticed that the position of their peaks does coincide with mine, except that they are labeled (006) instead. I tried reading up about this, and what I got was that they are parallel planes so it's fine, but I don't want to assume. Why does this happen, and can I still use these papers to verify the quality of my sample even though the number is different? Thank you!

Well, what was the material and its crystal structure? As an example, single crystal silicon, which is diamond cubic, does not exhibit the (001) reflection because of symmetry in the atomic basis cancelling it out. The (002) is the first one.

I think you're missing some information in your question, like the atomic spacing, wavelength of your X-ray and lattice constant, but to explain this in layman's terms, the XRD peak can be the same for two different lattice planes if they have the same $d$-space. This interplanar spacing can be calculated using the formula:
$$d^2_{h,\ k,\ l} = \frac{a^2}{h^2 + k^2 + l^2},$$
where:
$a$ = lattice constant
$d$ = interplanar spacing (which needs to be the same to get the same XRD peak)
$h,\ k,\ l$ = Miller indices.
This equation is just for cubic lattices, but you can find equations for other types of lattices here.
Hope this helped.
